# Склонение русских слов по падежам

Tags: php, веб-программирование, веб-служба, естественный-язык

Посоветуйте бесплатный сервис, относительно небольшую библиотеку или способы реализации для склонения русских слов по падежам на сайте. Раньше, знаю, был Яндекс.Склонятор, но сейчас он не доступен.

Comment: Склонение ФИО https://github.com/petrovich/petrovich-php

Answer (score 3):

http://morpher.ru/php/extension/
Первая ссылка из гугла. Вроде то, что Вам подходит.

Comment: Там подписка платная или покупка лицензии (бесплатный вариант до 1000 запросов в сутки), хотелось бы бесплатный аналог.

Comment: но последнее сообщение в их форуме меня насторожило... "Перестал работать веб-сервис. Это временная проблема?" - вопрос задан 7 месяцев назад, с тех пор - молчание

Comment: Если на проекте деньги зарабатываете, то купите это расширение. Работает достаточно хорошо. Подразумевается, что проект на VPS/VDS, благо сейчас виртуальный сервак можно арендовать от 200 руб